# The size of a histogram with a normal distribution in a R-plot

Tags: r

I use the following code to generate a histogram with the belonging normal distribution

```
h<-hist(df[,1], breaks=10, density=10, col="lightgray", xlab="Accuracy", main="Overall")    
xfit<-seq(min(df[,1]),max(df[,1]),length=40) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(df[,1]),sd=sd(df[,1])) 
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(df[,1]) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col="black", lwd=2)
```

How can I decrease the size of the plot so that I would be able to see the whole normal distribution in the plot?

[image: plot]

Comment: without `df` your code is not reproducible

Comment: df[,1] contains just 1000 normal distributed numbers

Comment: Include the argument `ylim=c(0,200)` in the call to `hist` (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df   <- data.frame(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000))
h    <- hist(df[,1], breaks=10, density=10, col="lightgray", xlab="Accuracy", main="Overall")    
xfit <- seq(min(df[,1]),max(df[,1]),length=40) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(df[,1]),sd=sd(df[,1])) 
yfit <- yfit*diff(h$mids[1:2])*length(df[,1]) 
par()$pin
par(pin=c(2,2))
lines(xfit, yfit, col="black", lwd=2)
```

From http://statmethods.net:

Margins and Graph Size

> You can control the margin size using the following parameters.
>
> ```
> option    description
> mar   numerical vector indicating margin size c(bottom, left, top, right) in lines. default = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1
> mai   numerical vector indicating margin size c(bottom, left, top, right) in inches
> pin   plot dimensions (width, height) in inches
> ```